# Path of Iphone crash logs on device

Tags: iphone, crash

Where are Iphone crash logs stored on the real device? Is there a reasonable way to get them without syncronizing the device with Itunes? I am not using Xcode as my main development environment. I am using Airplay sdk thus my primary dev environment is on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try iPhone Configuration Utility, available for Windows and Mac.

Comment: I have done a little bit of research based on the suggestions I received here. It seems that there isn't a quick and easy way to access to crash logs under windows without using Itunes. The Configuration Utility can show only the device console. I will accept this answer since it is the one that comes closer to satisfy my need.

Comment: Just saw this was answered before, apparently iTunes syncing is not required: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171633/accessing-crash-logs-on-iphones-used-for-ad-hoc-distribution

Answer (score 2):

You can sync your phone and then look on your computer in:
/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice

You can also use a service like Crittercism to upload crash logs automatically.
[www.crittercism.com](http://www.crittercism.com)

Answer (score 1):

You can access the crash logs from the Organizer window in Xcode.

Comment: My question didn't provide all the information needed. I am not using Xcode to develop.

Answer (score 0):

paths on device are:

```
/var/mobile/Library/Logs
/var/logs
```

But you can get it only in jailbroken device