# Testing for bugs on Apple devices that you do not own

Tags: iphone, unit-testing, debugging, ipad, ipod-touch

I'm starting to send out a beta version of my app for users to test. One came back and told me that the app crashes on her iPod Touch (2nd Gen). How do I debug for this considering I don't own one. All I have is the iPhone 4, yet there 9 other devices (each generation of iPhone, iPod Touch and iPad) that I would like my app to run on. Any advice?

**EDIT 1**

There is no iPod Touch hardware option in the simulator. Should I just assume that it is treated as an iPhone?

Comment: You also need to consider different OS versions, as well as hardware versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hoptoad App is great for this. You can sign up for free for up to 1 project, and the implementation is very easy.

http://hoptoadapp.com/pages/home

Comment: is this similar to TestFlight?

Comment: Nope this will actually collect crash logs from your apps and send it to HopToad app' server where you can see the stack trace, keep track of how many similar crashes you had, which ones have been fixed etc. You should give it a go, it's really good!

Answer (score 0):

You could try Apple's IOS simulator.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/125-Using_iOS_Simulator/ios_simulator_application.html

> To set the iOS release used in the
>   simulation environment, choose
>   Hardware > Version, and choose the
>   version you want to test on.

Comment: I don't think that's going to help to test for device-specific issues... (i.e. different generations of the same device family)

Comment: @Andre, it depends if it's an older OS version that causes the problem. You can select different IOS 'hardware versions' (which sounds like a contradiction in terms...)

Comment: True, if it's an iOS version that causes the problem the simulator will definitely help (and personally I've had more problems with iOS versions than with device-specific issues). But Eric asked for "different device generations" specifically, which was why I said I didn't think this would help to test for those.

Answer (score 0):

For starters get the crash logs from your users' devices and try to debug based on those. Not a big help in testing on devices you don't have, I know, but at least you'll be able to figure out what crashed on each device your beta testers have...

Comment: Any idea on how to get the crash log?

Comment: You can find information easily on Google ( http://aplus.rs/apple/how-to-find-crash-logs-for-iphone-applications-on-mac-vista-and-xp/ ) or SO ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171633/accessing-crash-logs-on-iphones-used-for-ad-hoc-distribution ) . But this will only be useful if you archived the build you sent to your testers, so that you can symbolicate the logs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports