# App runs fine in Xcode but crashes in ad-hoc distribution

Tags: ios, swift, crash, ad-hoc-distribution

I've been developing an iOS app for years and publishing it with ad-hoc distribution method. I had no problem previously.
Now, when I publish and upload it on website for organisation to test it, members can install the app on their devices fine, but as soon as they launch the app, it crashes on splash screen while  it runs on Xcode fine!

I have no idea what is the problem, and I have been searching for a solution for 2 days and I have got nothing.

> macOS version: 11.6 Xcode version : 13 iOS version: 15.0.1

**Update:**

```
Incident Identifier: 553C6AC8-ECA9-40D3-B433-5CC6304BFFFA
CrashReporter Key:   1d0c853c41e2477c3383142c94f5379de9c324b9
Hardware Model:      iPhone10,3
Process:             {{AppName}} [2208]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/49A22310-6360-4684-99E1-48E2F646F54A/{{AppName}}.app/{{AppName}}
Identifier:          com.{{AppName}}
Version:             1.12.0 (1)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.{{AppName}} [969]

Date/Time:           2021-10-14 23:49:42.2495 +0330
Launch Time:         2021-10-14 23:49:40.9020 +0330
OS Version:          iPhone OS 15.0.2 (19A404)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    7.02.00
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000001042f11fc
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: SIGNAL; [5]
Terminating Process: exc handler [2208]

Terminating Process: exc handler [2208]
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:   Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   {{AppName}}                                0x1042f11fc 0x1040d0000 + 2232828
1   {{AppName}}                                0x1042f0504 0x1040d0000 + 2229508
2   {{AppName}}                                0x1042ef694 0x1040d0000 + 2225812
3   UIKitCore                              0x18340334c -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 352
4   UIKitCore                              0x1835da624 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesWithActions:forCanvas:payload:fromOriginatingProcess:] + 3456
5   UIKitCore                              0x1835c380c -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1216
6   UIKitCore                              0x18342f9ec -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer completeApplicationLaunchWithFBSScene:transitionContext:] + 148
7   UIKitCore                              0x183292b00 _UIScenePerformActionsWithLifecycleActionMask + 96
8   UIKitCore                              0x1833b79f4 __101-[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:]_block_invoke + 196
9   UIKitCore                              0x1834ce204 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _performBlock:withApplicationOfDeactivationReasons:fromReasons:] + 240
10  UIKitCore                              0x1836fb064 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:] + 732
11  UIKitCore                              0x18368adac -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer uiScene:transitionedFromState:withTransitionContext:] + 336
12  UIKitCore                              0x1832939e8 __186-[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:]_block_invoke + 188
13  UIKitCore                              0x1833502f8 +[BSAnimationSettings(UIKit) tryAnimatingWithSettings:actions:completion:] + 812
14  UIKitCore                              0x183295778 _UISceneSettingsDiffActionPerformChangesWithTransitionContext + 248
15  UIKitCore                              0x18337b530 -[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:] + 356
16  UIKitCore                              0x1837d7bec __64-[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.573 + 772
17  UIKitCore                              0x1832c3f80 -[UIScene _emitSceneSettingsUpdateResponseForCompletion:afterSceneUpdateWork:] + 248
18  UIKitCore                              0x1833063ec -[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 264
19  UIKitCore                              0x183434684 -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 548
20  UIKitCore                              0x18337994c -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 360
21  FrontBoardServices                     0x191816fc4 -[FBSScene _callOutQueue_agent_didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 412
22  FrontBoardServices                     0x191839550 __94-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient createWithSceneID:groupID:parameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.180 + 100
23  FrontBoardServices                     0x1917f9714 -[FBSWorkspace _calloutQueue_executeCalloutFromSource:withBlock:] + 232
24  FrontBoardServices                     0x1917fab1c __94-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient createWithSceneID:groupID:parameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 312
25  libdispatch.dylib                      0x180aee2f0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
26  libdispatch.dylib                      0x180ac5f58 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct$VARIANT$armv81 + 212
27  FrontBoardServices                     0x1917fad7c __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 40
28  FrontBoardServices                     0x1917fa300 -[FBSSerialQueue _targetQueue_performNextIfPossible] + 176
29  FrontBoardServices                     0x1917fe3f0 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 24
30  CoreFoundation                         0x180e42220 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
31  CoreFoundation                         0x180e52248 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 204
32  CoreFoundation                         0x180d955e8 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 256
33  CoreFoundation                         0x180d9aa18 __CFRunLoopRun + 768
34  CoreFoundation                         0x180dadd8c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
35  GraphicsServices                       0x19aeba9a0 GSEventRunModal + 160
36  UIKitCore                              0x1835e2fa8 -[UIApplication _run] + 1080
37  UIKitCore                              0x18337722c UIApplicationMain + 2060
38  {{AppName}}                                0x1040d782c 0x1040d0000 + 30764
39  dyld                                   0x1048d4190 start + 444

Thread 1 name:   Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-qos
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1ba2f13dc stat + 8
1   Foundation                             0x182548b80 _NSFrameworkPathFromLibraryPath + 416
2   Foundation                             0x1825dd29c __25+[NSBundle allFrameworks]_block_invoke + 332
3   libdispatch.dylib                      0x180aee2f0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
4   libdispatch.dylib                      0x180abeac0 _dispatch_once_callout + 28
5   Foundation                             0x1825dd14c +[NSBundle allFrameworks] + 64
6   AccessibilityUtilities                 0x1955961e0 __43-[AXBinaryMonitor evaluateExistingBinaries]_block_invoke + 112
7   libdispatch.dylib                      0x180aed2ec _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
8   libdispatch.dylib                      0x180aee2f0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
9   libdispatch.dylib                      0x180ac5698 _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 712
10  libdispatch.dylib                      0x180ad2488 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 320
11  libdispatch.dylib                      0x180ad2c5c _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 160
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1da70aefc _pthread_wqthread + 224
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1da70aaa4 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1da70aa9c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3 name:   Dispatch queue: APMExperimentWorkerQueue
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1ba2f13dc stat + 8
1   libsqlite3.dylib                       0x1a37ebe80 0x1a37c6000 + 155264
2   libsqlite3.dylib                       0x1a37eab68 0x1a37c6000 + 150376
3   libsqlite3.dylib                       0x1a37ea1fc 0x1a37c6000 + 147964
4   libsqlite3.dylib                       0x1a38099d0 0x1a37c6000 + 276944
5   libsqlite3.dylib                       0x1a3807dc4 sqlite3_step + 308
6   {{AppName}}                                0x10440411c 0x1040d0000 + 3359004
7   {{AppName}}                                0x104403638 0x1040d0000 + 3356216
8   {{AppName}}                                0x1044028f8 0x1040d0000 + 3352824
9   {{AppName}}                                0x104403200 0x1040d0000 + 3355136
10  {{AppName}}                                0x1043886b8 0x1040d0000 + 2852536
11  {{AppName}}                                0x104388234 0x1040d0000 + 2851380
12  {{AppName}}                                0x104388110 0x1040d0000 + 2851088
13  {{AppName}}                                0x1043911cc 0x1040d0000 + 2888140
14  {{AppName}}                                0x104391174 0x1040d0000 + 2888052
15  {{AppName}}                                0x1043926e4 0x1040d0000 + 2893540
16  libdispatch.dylib                      0x180aed2ec _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
17  libdispatch.dylib                      0x180aee2f0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
18  libdispatch.dylib                      0x180ac9410 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain$VARIANT$armv81 + 596
19  libdispatch.dylib                      0x180ac9eb8 _dispatch_lane_invoke$VARIANT$armv81 + 388
20  libdispatch.dylib                      0x180ad376c _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 616
21  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1da70af38 _pthread_wqthread + 284
22  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1da70aaa4 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1ba2f0b70 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1ba2f1194 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                         0x180d96ad0 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 368
3   CoreFoundation                         0x180d9abb8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1184
4   CoreFoundation                         0x180dadd8c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
5   Foundation                             0x1824ecb6c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 232
6   Foundation                             0x18252bd6c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 88
7   UIKitCore                              0x183560950 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 512
8   Foundation                             0x18253964c __NSThread__start__ + 776
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1da70c458 _pthread_start + 116
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1da70aab0 thread_start + 8

Thread 5 name:   Dispatch queue: com.google.firebase.crashlytics.startup
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1ba2f0bc4 semaphore_timedwait_trap + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib                      0x180abda44 _dispatch_sema4_timedwait$VARIANT$armv81 + 60
2   libdispatch.dylib                      0x180abdfd4 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 72
3   FirebaseCrashlytics                    0x104fbb140 -[FIRCLSInstallIdentifierModel regenerateInstallIDIfNeeded] + 216
4   FirebaseCrashlytics                    0x104fc857c __91-[FIRCLSReportUploader prepareAndSubmitReport:dataCollectionToken:asUrgent:withProcessing:]_block_invoke_2 + 52
5   libdispatch.dylib                      0x180aee2f0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
6   libdispatch.dylib                      0x180abeac0 _dispatch_once_callout + 28
7   FirebaseCrashlytics                    0x104fc8544 __91-[FIRCLSReportUploader prepareAndSubmitReport:dataCollectionToken:asUrgent:withProcessing:]_block_invoke + 1156
8   FirebaseCrashlytics                    0x104faa980 FIRCLSApplicationActivity + 72
9   FirebaseCrashlytics                    0x104fc8078 -[FIRCLSReportUploader prepareAndSubmitReport:dataCollectionToken:asUrgent:withProcessing:] + 180
10  FirebaseCrashlytics                    0x104fb60e0 -[FIRCLSExistingReportManager processExistingActiveReportPath:dataCollectionToken:asUrgent:] + 192
11  FirebaseCrashlytics                    0x104fb5b64 -[FIRCLSExistingReportManager sendUnsentReportsWithToken:asUrgent:] + 220
12  FirebaseCrashlytics                    0x104fc770c -[FIRCLSReportManager beginReportUploadsWithToken:blockingSend:] + 144
13  FirebaseCrashlytics                    0x104fc70b4 __46-[FIRCLSReportManager startWithProfilingMark:]_block_invoke + 40
14  FBLPromises                            0x104f2f40c __56-[FBLPromise chainOnQueue:chainedFulfill:chainedReject:]_block_invoke.48 + 52
15  libdispatch.dylib                      0x180aed2ec _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
16  libdispatch.dylib                      0x180aee2f0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
17  libdispatch.dylib                      0x180ac94dc _dispatch_lane_serial_drain$VARIANT$armv81 + 800
18  libdispatch.dylib                      0x180ac9eb8 _dispatch_lane_invoke$VARIANT$armv81 + 388
19  libdispatch.dylib                      0x180ad376c _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 616
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1da70af38 _pthread_wqthread + 284
21  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1da70aaa4 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 6 name:   Dispatch queue: com.apple.UIKit.KeyboardManagement
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1ba2f1754 __ulock_wait + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib                      0x180abdde0 _dlock_wait + 52
2   libdispatch.dylib                      0x180abdbb8 _dispatch_thread_event_wait_slow$VARIANT$armv81 + 52
3   libdispatch.dylib                      0x180ad0560 __DISPATCH_WAIT_FOR_QUEUE__ + 336
4   libdispatch.dylib                      0x180ad015c _dispatch_sync_f_slow + 136
5   UIKitCore                              0x18344a10c __37-[_UIRemoteKeyboards startConnection]_block_invoke_3 + 112
6   CoreFoundation                         0x180db08e0 __invoking___ + 144
7   CoreFoundation                         0x180dcc5b8 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 300
8   Foundation                             0x182508910 __NSXPCCONNECTION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_REPLY_BLOCK__ + 20
9   Foundation                             0x1825280fc -[NSXPCConnection _decodeAndInvokeReplyBlockWithEvent:sequence:replyInfo:] + 552
10  Foundation                             0x18250475c __88-[NSXPCConnection _sendInvocation:orArguments:count:methodSignature:selector:withProxy:]_block_invoke_3 + 208
11  libxpc.dylib                           0x1da740cc8 _xpc_connection_reply_callout + 60
12  libxpc.dylib                           0x1da735004 _xpc_connection_call_reply_async + 76
13  libdispatch.dylib                      0x180aee368 _dispatch_client_callout3 + 16
14  libdispatch.dylib                      0x180ac2808 _dispatch_mach_msg_async_reply_invoke$VARIANT$armv81 + 344
15  libdispatch.dylib                      0x180ac92e8 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain$VARIANT$armv81 + 300
16  libdispatch.dylib                      0x180ac9eec _dispatch_lane_invoke$VARIANT$armv81 + 440
17  libdispatch.dylib                      0x180ad376c _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 616
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1da70af38 _pthread_wqthread + 284
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1da70aaa4 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 7 name:   Dispatch queue: com.apple.network.connections
Thread 7:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x197e812b8 objc_loadWeakRetained + 376
1   libnetwork.dylib                       0x181d680c4 __nw_resolver_create_dns_getaddrinfo_locked_block_invoke.165 + 80
2   libnetwork.dylib                       0x181d680c4 __nw_resolver_create_dns_getaddrinfo_locked_block_invoke.165 + 80
3   libdns_services.dylib                  0x1d9755f20 ___dnssd_getaddrinfo_activate_block_invoke + 168
4   libdispatch.dylib                      0x180aee2f0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
5   libdispatch.dylib                      0x180ac59f0 _dispatch_continuation_pop$VARIANT$armv81 + 436
6   libdispatch.dylib                      0x180ad6e3c _dispatch_source_invoke$VARIANT$armv81 + 1320
7   libdispatch.dylib                      0x180acb02c _dispatch_workloop_invoke$VARIANT$armv81 + 1640
8   libdispatch.dylib                      0x180ad376c _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 616
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1da70af38 _pthread_wqthread + 284
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1da70aaa4 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 8 name:   Dispatch queue: com.google.perf.configUpdate
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1ba2f1754 __ulock_wait + 8
1   libsystem_platform.dylib               0x1da705110 _os_unfair_lock_lock_slow + 192
2   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x197e85ce8 objc_initWeak + 124
3   FirebaseRemoteConfig                   0x1051d14d4 -[RCNConfigExperiment loadExperimentFromTable] + 44
4   FirebaseRemoteConfig                   0x1051d1474 -[RCNConfigExperiment initWithDBManager:experimentController:] + 484
5   FirebaseRemoteConfig                   0x1051c70e4 -[FIRRemoteConfig initWithAppName:FIROptions:namespace:DBManager:configContent:analytics:] + 440
6   FirebaseRemoteConfig                   0x1051ca404 -[FIRRemoteConfigComponent remoteConfigForNamespace:] + 808
7   FirebaseRemoteConfig                   0x1051c6dd0 +[FIRRemoteConfig remoteConfigWithFIRNamespace:app:] + 148
8   FirebasePerformance                    0x10514a880 __38+[FPRRemoteConfigFlags sharedInstance]_block_invoke + 80
9   libdispatch.dylib                      0x180aee2f0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
10  libdispatch.dylib                      0x180abeac0 _dispatch_once_callout + 28
11  FirebasePerformance                    0x10514a82c +[FPRRemoteConfigFlags sharedInstance] + 60
12  FirebasePerformance                    0x105138b64 -[FPRConfigurations setupRemoteConfigFlags] + 148
13  FirebasePerformance                    0x105138a98 __27-[FPRConfigurations update]_block_invoke + 76
14  libdispatch.dylib                      0x180aed2ec _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
15  libdispatch.dylib                      0x180aee2f0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
16  libdispatch.dylib                      0x180ac9410 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain$VARIANT$armv81 + 596
17  libdispatch.dylib                      0x180ac9eb8 _dispatch_lane_invoke$VARIANT$armv81 + 388
18  libdispatch.dylib                      0x180ad376c _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 616
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1da70af38 _pthread_wqthread + 284
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1da70aaa4 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 9 name:   Dispatch queue: com.google.firebase.crashlytics.ios.binary-images
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1ba2f2b38 access + 8
1   Foundation                             0x182512bdc -[NSBundle initWithPath:] + 372
2   Foundation                             0x182531588 +[NSBundle bundleWithPath:] + 36
3   FirebaseCrashlytics                    0x104fac24c __FIRCLSBinaryImageChanged_block_invoke + 696
4   libdispatch.dylib                      0x180aed2ec _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
5   libdispatch.dylib                      0x180aee2f0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
6   libdispatch.dylib                      0x180ac9410 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain$VARIANT$armv81 + 596
7   libdispatch.dylib                      0x180ac9eb8 _dispatch_lane_invoke$VARIANT$armv81 + 388
8   libdispatch.dylib                      0x180ad376c _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 616
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1da70af38 _pthread_wqthread + 284
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1da70aaa4 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1da70aa9c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 11 name:  com.google.firebase.crashlytics.MachExceptionServer
Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1ba2f23e8 write + 8
1   FirebaseCrashlytics                    0x104fbb650 FIRCLSSDKFileLog + 316
2   FirebaseCrashlytics                    0x104fbd4c4 FIRCLSMachExceptionServer + 1004
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1da70c458 _pthread_start + 116
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1da70aab0 thread_start + 8

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1da70aa9c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1da70aa9c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 14:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1da70aa9c start_wqthread + 0


No thread state (register information) available

Binary Images:
       0x1040d0000 -        0x10451ffff {{AppName}} arm64  <3ae785ec3f5d36919fb7c01330e5b80d> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/49A22310-6360-4684-99E1-48E2F646F54A/{{AppName}}.app/{{AppName}}
       0x1830f5000 -        0x18487cfff UIKitCore arm64  <4c9b5192c562355cbfca71961f92935e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore
       0x1917f0000 -        0x19188efff FrontBoardServices arm64  <0d3af6437c5b34afac62d438b1d74315> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices
       0x180a8a000 -        0x180b0cfff libdispatch.dylib arm64  <5d722afcfb8c3769bf66167bb94a6133> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
       0x180d90000 -        0x1811cafff CoreFoundation arm64  <fe94d75f5f1d3127ba500161d8817ee6> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
       0x19aeb9000 -        0x19aec1fff GraphicsServices arm64  <87b24bb5a3dd358d9abba1f70544a383> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
       0x1048bc000 -        0x10490ffff dyld arm64  <d7a0282e93de3a1e981327e84517cc96> /usr/lib/dyld
       0x1ba2f0000 -        0x1ba321fff libsystem_kernel.dylib arm64  <83a7e9554c943d9d9c1163fe9c36fbd7> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
       0x1824d5000 -        0x1827b3fff Foundation arm64  <b17c0d3bcabb321290560791b2521900> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
       0x19554d000 -        0x195665fff AccessibilityUtilities arm64  <ca01cc924b7b3328b02bc17837fbbbb4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccessibilityUtilities.framework/AccessibilityUtilities
       0x1da70a000 -        0x1da719fff libsystem_pthread.dylib arm64  <c685b49359ff3f13a9b33d3bb868ccd5> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
       0x1a37c6000 -        0x1a3951fff libsqlite3.dylib arm64  <7301a6c6c94335029598d1e1a2fbab71> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
       0x104fa4000 -        0x104fe3fff FirebaseCrashlytics arm64  <911707c79bfb3abcbbdafbb1893a35b3> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/49A22310-6360-4684-99E1-48E2F646F54A/{{AppName}}.app/Frameworks/FirebaseCrashlytics.framework/FirebaseCrashlytics
       0x104f28000 -        0x104f37fff FBLPromises arm64  <c416500f6a1a350c8f8edb5696eeaeda> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/49A22310-6360-4684-99E1-48E2F646F54A/{{AppName}}.app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises
       0x1da728000 -        0x1da75afff libxpc.dylib arm64  <fbe92a1095e630599061c21ef625fbd5> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
       0x197e7c000 -        0x197eb1fff libobjc.A.dylib arm64  <aaf2058b0b5d35aca9b881383e71814b> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
       0x1819f8000 -        0x18245dfff libnetwork.dylib arm64  <ee6d55995b6e3aacabc705f56b4ee2fb> /usr/lib/libnetwork.dylib
       0x1d9754000 -        0x1d975cfff libdns_services.dylib arm64  <8384989ee1b535a79501d7c856fce4d7> /usr/lib/libdns_services.dylib
       0x1da6fd000 -        0x1da708fff libsystem_platform.dylib arm64  <4bdfc54acdcb3b799ffc3d9e226fd47d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
       0x1051c0000 -        0x1051dffff FirebaseRemoteConfig arm64  <8971dc73d9b533ea9977ed8fb425049d> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/49A22310-6360-4684-99E1-48E2F646F54A/{{AppName}}.app/Frameworks/FirebaseRemoteConfig.framework/FirebaseRemoteConfig
       0x10512c000 -        0x10515bfff FirebasePerformance arm64  <53e1cd2d04413ceabe13595d9df8d665> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/49A22310-6360-4684-99E1-48E2F646F54A/{{AppName}}.app/Frameworks/FirebasePerformance.framework/FirebasePerformance

Error Formulating Crash Report:thread_get_state(PAGEIN) returned 0x10000003: (ipc/send) invalid destination port
thread_get_state(EXCEPTION) returned 0x10000003: (ipc/send) invalid destination port
thread_get_state(FLAVOR) returned 0x10000003: (ipc/send) invalid destination port

EOF
```

Comment: Just figure it out for me with this crash log?  It souds like a wild goose chase.

Comment: You're going to need to get a crash log off one of your customers in order to diagnose the issue. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171633/accessing-crash-logs-on-iphones-used-for-ad-hoc-distribution) for hints.

Comment: @trojanfoe this link was so helpful, and now I'm seeing the device console, what should I look for? any more hint?

Comment: @Am1rFT Once you have the crash log you should probably follow [this article](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/diagnosing-issues-using-crash-reports-and-device-logs) from Apple.

Comment: @trojanfoe do you see anything in the crash log that could help me solve the problem?

Comment: @matt Nothing much, in appDelegate i'm configuring the firebase and notification and setting some fonts the whole app

Comment: As I investigated deeply, i found out that the reason my app is crashing is because of the custom font that I'm using is not included in my .ipa file but it is available in the app. I believe this is a xCode bug which can not archive my fonts @matt

Answer (score 0):

As I investigated deeply, I found out that the reason my app is crashing is because of the custom font that I'm using is not included in my arcchive file but it is available in the project and in the info.plist and in Copy Bundle Resources.

***⚠️This is just a solution for now until I figure out why the Font is not in the archive file!***

1. I selected the archive and then "show in finder".

*the extension of archive should be : .xcarchive*

2. Right clicked my archive in finder and selected "show package contents".
3. Right clicked my App and selected "show package contents" in Products>Applications>{{AppName}}.App
4. Dropped my fonts here and distributed the archive and it worked fine without any crash.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, have you figured out why the font is not in the archive file ?

Comment: I downloaded the log of the application from the device and then as i investigated I found out the font was not included in the .ipa. you can follow the comments in the question to understand how to check the log.